# How to best serve a GridFS stored file (PDF) via my Express.js driven API to a connected client (iOS)?

Tags: ios, node.js, mongodb, express, gridfs

I'm developing a REST HTTP API that has iOS clients connecting to it. The way it's currently set up (and tested with POSTman chrome ext) is that I make the request for the resource, and I have to wait for the whole thing to get read in and spit out for it to show up as a response.

Is this a good method for iOS and Mac client consumption or is there a better method for serving from GridFS?

I'm doing the following:

```
  // Download a PDF
  app.get('/api/download-pdf/:pdf_id', function(req, res){
    var gfs = new mongodb.GridStore(mongoose.connection.db, ObjectID(req.params.pdf_id), "r");
    gfs.open(function(err,gs) {
      if (err){
        res.send(500);
      } 
      else{
        gs.read(function(err,data) {
          res.header('Content-type','application/pdf');
          res.send(data);
          gs.close(function(err) {});
          if (err) throw(err);
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the node driver now supports streaming to/from GridFS http://christiankvalheim.com/post/29753345741/new-features-in-the-driver-for-mongodb-2-2?8e43c3e0

`gs.pipe(anotherStream)`

See [Streams](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html)

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I think that's what I was hoping, but wouldn't that stream it to another file location on disk? How would I go about streaming it directly to the client?

Comment: Ah, I think you're saying I can just do `gs.pipe(res)`

Comment: read up on nodejs streams, you can stream to files, response objects, and more.

Comment: Thanks aaron, Can you please tell how to capture files from file type 'multiple' or more than one file selects in a form post. As I think I am able to capture and stream only one file.